# Procmail not execute shell command

Tags: procmail, parsing

i need launch a script when receive an email with specific subject, i've try fetchmail + procmail, this my configuration

**.fetchmailrc**

```
set no bouncemail
defaults:
  antispam -1 
  batchlimit 100
poll imap.googlemail.com protocol IMAP auth password
user "test@test.com" is root here
password 'xxxxx'
ssl
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -f %F -d %T";
```

**.procmailrc**

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/sbin
MAILDIR=/var/mail
LOGFILE=/var/log/procmail.log

:0
* ^Subject: "Test OK"
| echo "Test" >> /var/log/test.log
```

When send mail with subject `Test OK`, i see in procmail log the lines:

```
From myemail@gmail.com  Sat Dec  8 18:41:16 2018
 Subject: Test OK
  Folder: /var/mail/root                             5304
```

But no execute the `echo`, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Does your personal `.procmailrc` really have the privileges to write to `/var/log/procmail.log`? This seems like a misconfiguration, either way.

Answer (score 1):

The `Subject` line in the log message doesn't have double quotes around it; hence, your regex didn't match.

A better test is probably to save the entire message to a particular folder.

Perhaps see also [Procmail degugging tips](http://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html)